# Android Java Webview manipulate XHR/AJAX-Request

Tags: java, android, http, webview, python-requests

I need to create an Android-Application that opens a Website via a WebView. At some point, an AJAX/XHR-Request starts, which I could also intercept via the

```
shouldInterceptRequest(...)
```

function. It has a specific URL. But i need to change a value in die Request-Body. So in the first place I need to get the Request-Body, parse the contents, change some values and then do the request with the changed body.

Is that somehow possible via an Android-WebView?